# Label text in center and moving depending on number of text lines in the label below

Tags: swift, uilabel, constraints

My UILabel is pinned to the top of the cell, just like UIImage but if the text below has f.e. 1 line (its also in UILabel)  my top UILabel is in other place.
Here are my constraints and labels declaration. Thanks to anyone who will try to solve my problem :) I tried using sizeToFit method on my UILabels

```
var albumImage: UIImageView = {
    let view = UIImageView()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    return view
}()

var albumName: UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.numberOfLines = 0
    view.sizeToFit()
    return view
}()

var bandName: UILabel = {
    let view = UILabel()
    view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    view.sizeToFit()
    return view
}()

override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    drawLayout()
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("ERROR")
}



func drawLayout(){

    let guide = self.safeAreaLayoutGuide


    //albumImage
    addSubview(albumImage)
    addSubview(albumName)
    addSubview(bandName)

    albumImage.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    albumImage.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
    albumImage.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.leadingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    albumImage.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    albumImage.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true

    //albumTitle
    albumName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bandName.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
    albumName.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.bottomAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true
    albumName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: albumImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
    albumName.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: guide.trailingAnchor, constant: -8).isActive = true

    //bandName
    bandName.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: albumImage.topAnchor).isActive = true
    bandName.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: albumImage.trailingAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
}
```

Comment: where is the image  ??

Comment: I set my image in the UIViewController where I have my UITableView, image shows well, dependant on the height of the cell although